# Error: "cannot determine truth value of Relational" But not using any operations to do with sympy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have read the other threads about this particular error and each one had to do with a specific sympy function being used, however in my case it is happening on a line that is just a comparison in an if statement, something i've done a million times and I cannot figure out why. It says it's at the "if abs(Yp-Yn) < e" line and I've used that same line in other code many times but never ran into this error. I would appreciate any advice on what might be causing this. thank you!!

````
from sympy import *

def f_ice(alpha, Y_s, L, y):
    return alpha*(y + Y_s)/(y*(y + L))

def HeunMeth(alpha, Y_0, Y_s, L, T, N):
    h = T/N
    solution = np.zeros(N+1)
    solution[0] = -Y_0
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        f = f_ice(alpha, Y_s, L, solution[n-1])
        Y_inter = solution[n-1] + h*(f)
        f_s = f_ice(alpha, Y_s, L, Y_inter)
        solution[n] = solution[n-1] + (h/2)*(f + f_s) 
    return solution

def Fice(Y_s, L, y):
    return (((y**2)/2) - (Y_s - L)*y + Y_s*(Y_s - L)*log(abs(y + Y_s)))

def drvFice(Y_s, L, y):
    y0, Y_s0, L0 = symbols("y Y_s L")
    deriv = diff((((y0**2)/2) - (Y_s0 - L0)*y0 + Y_s0*(Y_s0 - L0)*log(abs(y0 + Y_s0))), y0)
    return (deriv.evalf(subs={y0: y, Y_s0: Y_s, L0: L}))

def newton_for_ice(L, Y_0, Y_s, alpha, t, N_max, epsilon, Y_init):
    Yn = Y_init
    Yp = Yn + 2*epsilon
    func = Fice(Y_s, L, -Y_0) - alpha*t
    for n in range(1, N_max+1):
        if abs(Yp - Yn) < epsilon:
            print('Approximation of ', Yn, 'found after ', n, 'interations.')
            return
        elif drvFice(Y_s, L, Yn) != 0:
            Yp = Yn
            Yn = Yn - Fice(Y_s, L, Yn)/drvFice(Y_s, L, Yn)
            error = abs(Yp - Yn)
        else:
            break
    return Yn


L = 1
Y_0 = 0.01
Y_s = 0.75
alpha = 2/3
t = 5
N_max = 20
epsilon = 0.00001
Y_init = 1

solution = newton_for_ice(L, Y_0, Y_s, alpha, t, N_max, epsilon, Y_init)
print(solution)```


and the error shows as:

``` ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_153/4233959850.py in <module>
     55 
     56 print('h')
---> 57 solution = newton_for_ice(L, Y_0, Y_s, alpha, t, N_max, epsilon, Y_init)
     58 print(solution)

/tmp/ipykernel_153/4233959850.py in newton_for_ice(L, Y_0, Y_s, alpha, t, N_max, epsilon, Y_init)
     33     print(func)
     34     for n in range(1, N_max+1):
---> 35         if error < epsilon:
     36             print('Approximation of ', Yn, 'found after ', n, 'interations.')
     37             return

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py in __bool__(self)
    396 
    397     def __bool__(self):
--> 398         raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
    399 
    400     def _eval_as_set(self):

TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational```
````

Comment: numpy is not Python. Equality of 2 arrays is not a boolean but an array of booleans...

Comment: @SergeBallesta sorry i'm confused, i thought i was simply making a comparison. it seemed to work with other codes is this cause I have imported numpy?

Comment: What is `abs(Yp - Yn)` at this point`? Or is it `error`?  You code doesnt quite match the error message. The error message implies it's a sympy expression, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

When I add some prints right before the problem `if` line:

```
print(Yp-Yn)
expr = abs(Yp - Yn) < epsilon
print(expr, type(expr))
```

the display is

for initial values, `Yp-Yn` is a number and the test a simple boolean

```
1.999999999990898e-05
False <class 'bool'>
```

but in the next loop, with new `Yp` and `Yn`:

```
0.645072039762108/(1.25 - 0.107142857142857*Subs(Derivative(re(y), y), y, 1))
0.645072039762108*Abs(1/(0.107142857142857*Subs(Derivative(re(y), y), y, 1) - 1.25)) < 1.0e-5 
<class 'sympy.core.relational.StrictLessThan'>
```

`Yp-Yn` is a sympy expression, so `expr` is `sympy` `relational`.  That cannot be used in a simple Python `if`.  A similar problem often comes up when people try to use a numpy array or Pandas series in a test.  They don't produce a simple True/False, but rather an array of such.

Without any clues as to what's different between this run and those millions of working cases, we can't help.

The new `Yn` is a sympy expression.  You'll have to traceback through the code to determine how that arises.  Since you do a generic `sympy` import, it's hard to tell, just from reading, where you are using sympy functions and variables.

In case it matters, I tested this in a `isympy` session, which imports `sympy` in the same way, and defines some basic symbols.

### digging further

On further checking it looks like the `subs` in `drvFice` are not producing a number:

```
Subs(Derivative(re(y), y), y, 1)
```

`deriv` in this function is not a closed form:

```
L + Y_s*(-L + Y_s)*((re(Y_s) + re(y))*Derivative(re(y), y) + (im(Y_s) + im(y))*Derivative(im(y), y))*sign(Y_s + y)/((Y_s + y)*Abs(Y_s + y)) - Y_s + y
```

Noting the `re()`, `im()` terms, I tried defining the symbols as real

```
y0, Y_s0, L0 = symbols("y Y_s L", real=True)
```

now `deriv` is

```
L + Y_s*(-L + Y_s)*sign(Y_s + y)/Abs(Y_s + y) - Y_s + y
```

and the `subs` work, and whole `solution` iteration runs.

It's even simpler with positive:

```
y0, Y_s0, L0 = symbols("y Y_s L", real=True, positive=True)
```